# Ubuntu LiveDVD problem

Tags: 12.10, uefi, livedvd

I am new to Linux, I tried Ubuntu 12.10. On a Laptop pre-loaded with windows 7, that was later upgraded to windows 8.

I created a Live DVD, and booted the disc. When I boot from the disc, it goes through a black screen for a brief moment, and soon after greets me with a purple screen, that has what appears at the bottom as a stick figure guy, and a keyboard with a circle around it.

Then it goes to a black screen with a flashing underscore. This goes on for minutes, and soon my dvd drive stops running, and the underscore continues to flash, and will not greet me to the setup screen. I currently have quick boot disabled.

I know there are problems with the UEFI format. I have downloaded, and burned both secure remix 64 bit, along with the traditional 12.10 64 bit. However the trial and error guide for UEFI does not describe how to solve my current Issue. instead it says when you click try Ubuntu it brings a error. This is not my problem, but a reference.

Comment: check that the disc was correctly burned -- more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145611/why-does-my-burned-ubuntu-dvd-have-a-different-hash-checksum-than-the-iso/148039#148039. I usually end up using a USB and UNetBootin rather than a disc. You could also try Ubuntu 32-bit version and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have checked my disc, and it was burned correctly. My computer is a gaming PC so there should be no reason to try a 32 bit version. I will try it just to be safe though. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: OK my problem is solved. It was something completely unrelated. I am going to list the solution for future reference for anybody that needs it. I just had to press enter when the keyboard appeared, and once i got through language i pressed F6, and selected nomodset. I will note that my native resolution (1920x1080) was not available but i am working on a solution. Thanks to carnendil for advice, even though it was not my solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK my problem is solved. It was something completely unrelated. I am going to list the solution for future reference for anybody that needs it.

I just had to press enter when the keyboard appeared, and once I got through language I pressed <kbd>F6</kbd>, and selected `nomodset`.
I will note that my native resolution (1920x1080) was not available but I am working on a solution. Thanks to carnendil for advice, even though it was not my solution.